# Read from file into variable - Bash Script

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, list, shell

I'm working on a bash script to backup MySQL. I need to read from a file a series of strings and pass them to a variable in my script. Example:

Something like this will be in the file (file.txt)

```
database1 table1
database1 table4
database2
database3 table2
```

My script needs to read the file and put these strings in a variable like:

```
#! bin/bash
LIST="database1.table1|database1.table4|database2|database3.table2"
```

**Edit.** I changed my mind, now I need this output:

```
database1.table1.*|database1.table4.*|database2*.*|database3.table2.*
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: You need to fix the shebang too, it'd be `#!/bin/bash`

Answer (score 6):

You could use `tr` to replace the newlines and spaces:

```
LIST=$(tr ' \n' '.|' < file.txt)
```

Since the last line of the input file is likely to contain a newline by itself, you'd need to get rid of it:

```
LIST=$(tr ' ' '.' < file.txt | paste -sd'|')
```

Answer (score 5):

Using awk:

```
s=$(awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS='.' ORS='|' file)
LIST="${s%|}"

echo "$LIST"
database1.table1|database1.table4|database2|database3.table2
```

Comment: This is great!!. I forgot to mention one thing. I need to also add some wildcards to the output string. The conditions are: if we read database2 the output should be database2*.* and if we read a database and a table the output should be database1.table1.*  The final result I'm looking for is: database1.table1.*|database1.table4.*|database2*.*|database3.table2.*

    Please help :)

Comment: That actually changes the very nature of the problem. If you open a new question linking to this one I will make an attempt to solve it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412765/read-from-file-into-variable-bash-script-take2

Comment: May I know what's wrong with the answer since you unaccepted it.

Answer (score 3):

bash (version 4 I believe)

```
mapfile -t lines < file.txt           # read lines of the file into an array
lines=("${lines[@]// /.}")            # replace all spaces with dots 
str=$(IFS='|'; echo "${lines[*]}")    # join the array with pipe
echo "$str"
```

```
database1.table1|database1.table4|database2|database3.table2
```

---

```
mapfile -t lines < file.txt
for ((i=0; i<${#lines[@]}; i++)); do
    [[ ${lines[i]} == *" "* ]] && lines[i]+=" *" || lines[i]+="* *"
done
str=$(IFS='|'; echo "${lines[*]// /.}") 
echo "$str"
```

```
database1.table1.*|database1.table4.*|database2*.*|database3.table2.*
```

Comment: You don't need the auxiliary variable since the purpose is only to print to stdout. In a subshell `(IFS='|'; echo "${lines[*]}")` is enough. Actually, you don't even need the auxiliary lines either: `mapfile -t lines < files.txt; (IFS='|'; echo "${lines[*]// /.}")`

Comment: How could I get this output instead `database1.table1.*|database1.table4.*|database2*.*|database3.table2.*` - Please notice the `.*` vs `*.*` - In other words: If there is only database with no table i need to add `*.*` at the end and when there is a database.table i need to add `.*`

Answer (score 2):

You can just replace the new lines with a charater that you need using `sed`, if it doesn't occur in the data.

For example

```
FOO=$(sed '{:q;N;y/ /./;s/\n/|/g;t q}' /home/user/file.txt)
```

Comment: How could I get this output instead `database1.table1.*|database1.table4.*|database2*.*|database3.table2.*` - Please notice the `.*` vs `*.*` - In other words: If there is only database with no table i need to add `*.*` at the end and when there is a database.table i need to add `.*`