# Read from file into variable - Bash Script take2

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, shell, awk

This is a second part of [Read from file into variable - Bash Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23390579/read-from-file-into-variable-bash-script/23390691?noredirect=1#comment35875691_23390691)

I have a bash script that reads strings in a file parses and assigns it to a variable. The file looks like this (file.txt):

```
database1 table1
database1 table4
database2
database3 table2
```

Using awk in the script:

```
s=$(awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS='.' ORS='|' file.txt)
LIST="${s%|}"

echo "$LIST"
database1.table1|database1.table4|database2|database3.table2
```

But I need to add some wildcards at the end of each substring. I need this result:

```
database1.table1.*|database1.table4.*|database2*.*|database3.table2.*
```

The conditions are: if we read database2 the output should be database2*.* and if we read a database and a table the output should be database1.table1.*

Answer (score 0):

Use this awk with `ORS='.*|'`:

```
s=$(awk '$0=="database2"{$0=$0 "*.*";print;next} {$2=$2 ".*"}1' OFS='.' ORS='|' file.txt)
LIST="${s%|}"

echo "$LIST"
database1.table1.*|database1.table4.*|database2*.*|database3.table2.*
```

Comment: This is quite close. But OP is looking for `database2*.*` instead of `database2.*`, though I have my doubts on his expected output.

Comment: Yes I have same doubt because `database2.*` appears more correct regex

Comment: Thats correct. I'm looking for database2*.* instead of database2.*

Comment: @andresg3: How are you going to use `database2*.*` Do you really want to match 0 or more occurrences of digit `2` using this regex?

Comment: Maybe it's a *glob*, not a *regex*.

Comment: more than zero occurrences

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the (slightly odd) regex is correct the following awk script works for me on your example input.

```
BEGIN {OFS="."; ORS="|"}
!$2 {$1=$1"*"}
{$(NF+1)="*"}
1
```

1. Set `OFS` and `ORS`.
2. If we do not have a second field add a `*` to our first field.
3. Add a `*` as a final field.
4. Print the line.

Run as `awk -f script.awk inputfile` where the above script is in the `script.awk` (or whatever) file.

Comment: @andresg3 That was just the awk script body itself. Sorry if that was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this.

`script.sh` containing the following code:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while IFS='' read -r line ;do
  database=$(awk '{print $1}' <<< $line)
     table=$(awk '{print $2}' <<< $line)
  if [ "${table}" == '' ] ;then
    list=(${list}\|${database}\*\.\*)
  else
    list=(${list}\|${database}\.${table}\.\*)
  fi
done <file.txt

list=$(cut -c 2- <<< ${list})
echo ${list}

exit 0
```

`file.txt` containing the following data:

```
database1 table1
database1 table4
database2
database3 table2
```

Script output is the following:

```
database1.table1.*|database1.table4.*|database2*.*|database3.table2.*
```

Tested in BASH version:
`GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`